# opencart 4 extension | overriding home Controller proplem

Tags: opencart, opencart-module

hallow everyone , I'm trying to develop theme as extension in OpenCart 4 for my site but when i try to override the home controller it does not changed at all , other controller  was changed normally

### my  startup controller

i need to develop a custume theme and i need to pass data from control panel to it.

```
    `<?php

namespace Opencart\Catalog\Controller\Extension\Printinos\Startup;

class override extends \Opencart\System\Engine\Controller
{
   public function index():void
   {
       if ($this->config->get('theme_printinos_status')) {
           $this->event->register('controller/*/before', new \Opencart\System\Engine\Action('extension/printinos/startup/override|event'));
       }
   }
    public function event(string &$route, array &$args): void
    {
        $override = [
            'common/header',
            'common/home',
            'common/footer',
            'common/column_left',
            'common/column_right',
            'common/column_bottom',
            'common/column_top',
            'common/currency',
            'common/language',
            'common/maintenance',
            'common/menu',
            'common/pagination',
            'common/search',


        ];

        if (in_array($route, $override)) {
            $route = 'extension/printinos/' . $route;
        }
    }

}`
--------------------------------------------
my home controller
`<?php
namespace Opencart\Catalog\Controller\Extension\Printinos\Common;
class Home extends \Opencart\System\Engine\Controller {
    public function index(): void {
        $this->document->setTitle($this->config->get('config_meta_title'));
        $this->document->setDescription($this->config->get('config_meta_description'));
        $this->document->setKeywords($this->config->get('config_meta_keyword'));

        $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
        $data['column_right'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_right');
        $data['content_top'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_top');
        $data['content_bottom'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_bottom');
        $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');
        $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');
        var_dump($data);
        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('common/home', $data));
    }
}`
```